# Entering login information for a site that doesn't use forms with Mechanize/Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, mechanize

I need to log in to a site to run some scripts. Mechanize with Nokogiri looks perfect for the task, but I'm having a hard time inputting the login information since the input fields aren't located in forms (agent.page.forms.first yields nil):

```
    <div class="loginform" id="login_form">
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="loginname" tabindex="1"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="password" id="password" tabindex="2"/>
        <input type="text" id="password_text" style="display:none;"/>
      </div>
      <div class="signin"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sp" id="login_submit_btn"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Is it possible to somehow navigate to the input elements (they're the only ones on the page) and then submit my username and password to log in? If Mechanize isn't capable of doing something like this, are there alternatives? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would better check inside the whole source (including javascript) how the website connect you.
It should be a HTTP POST request in my opinion... and use it to log directly without parsing the main page by GET request but using [`Mechanize post method`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html#method-i-post) instead :

```
agent = Mechanize.new
url = 'http://website.com/hidden_login_page.php'
page = agent.post(url, {"login" => "foo", "password" => "bar"})
```

Hope it helps too.

Comment: Yikes, it looks like there is indeed some javascript going on, but I don't currently have the requisite skillz to decipher how it's actually posting. Thanks for the suggestion though. I'll keep chugging at it.

Comment: which website and url page is it for?

Comment: Haha, I'd rather not say openly, but may I message it to you? It's somewhat sensitive (though not in the illegal or unethical sense). But in any case, as the other commenter suggested, I used Selenium and after some finagling, it did the trick! Thanks to you and Sean for your help.

Comment: Sure you can message it to me and I'll take a look on it... I think Selenium seems to be more difficult to code in my opinion. And I'm not sure it is much more versatile. Feel free sending me the url.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had an issue like this. Try the following in mechanize:

```
page.field_with(:name => "loginname").value = "foo"
page.field_with(:name => "password").value = "bar"
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @sean for the tip! Unfortunately, I'm not sure if page can perform the field_with method. I get the error 

`nokotest.rb:11:in <main>': undefined method field_with' for #<Mechanize::Page: 0xe5c638> (NoMethodError)`

when I tried your really helpful suggestion. Again, I think forms are needed in order to use field_with... Any other suggestions?

Comment: Only thing I can think is to use Selenium and get it to record your login action and then export it so you can work with it that way.

Comment: Selenium did the trick! Thanks for the suggestion Sean. It's a bit slower than what Mechanize might be able to do, but for now, it'll get the job done.